# Booking system based on Charge 2.0

Tags: search, plugin-charge

I am building an event booking system for a restaurant using Charge 2.0. Everything is working great, but having problems implementing a feature that shows how many spots are left.

An Event channel entry (created by the restaurant) provides parameters such as price, event name, etc and passes them to a Charge form. The Event entry also includes a field that specifies the maximum number of guests.

The Charge form includes a field for specifying a 'number of guests' for the booking. To indicate how many spots are left, we first need to calculate how many guests have already been booked, which is a simple matter of getting the 'numberOfGuests' field from all of the existing Charge entries and summing them. The problem arises when trying to filter the results using a Search parameter, which limits the entries to a specific event (the Event name is passed to the Charge description field). Here is a bit of the code:

```
{% set q = 'description:' ~ '"' ~ entry.title ~ '"' %}
{% for entry in craft.charge.charges().search(q) %}
   //get the number of guests
```

I tried a few different things, including a wildcard search, and none of them return any results. Does anyone know if the Charge model supports a Search parameter?

Comment: Upon further testing it seems the Search parameter will work with custom fields, but seemingly not with the Charge 'description' field. If I print the Charge description field it returns the expected values.

Answer (score 3):

Developer of [Charge](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/charge) here.

Yes - Charge supports all the native Craft criteria search parameters for fields.

Like you mentioned, there are a few special fields that aren't supported currently within that. Those are fields like `description`, `notes` etc.. The **supported** direct attributes on the Charge model that can be searched (in addition to all the basic ElementType attributes) are :

- `userId`
- `sourceUrl`
- `timestamp`
- `hash`
- `customerId`
- `mode`
- `meta`

This is in addition to all Craft fields you might have attached to the charges.

For example - if I wanted to find all the charges based on a specific `customerId` (the stripe identifier), it'd look something like this :

```
{% set charges = craft.charge.charges({ customerId : 'cus_00000000' }) %}
```

They can be of course be combined, so all charges for that customer only in live mode :

```
{% set charges = craft.charge.charges({ mode: 'live', customerId : 'cus_00000000' }) %}
```

If we had a field on the charge model with a name of `ourCustomField`, we could search for that like :

```
{% set charges = craft.charge.charges({ search : { query : 'ourCustomField:' ~ someSearchValue }}) %}
```

And also, we could combine all those into a single thing too:

```
{% set charges = craft.charge.charges(
   { mode: 'live', 
     customerId : 'cus_00000000', 
     search : { 
        query : 'ourCustomField:' ~ someSearchValue 
   }}) %}
```

Or in the alternative syntax, that could be:

```
{% set q = 'ourCustomField:' ~ someSearchValue %}
{% set charges = craft.charge.charges()
      .customerId('cus_00000000')
      .mode('live')
      .search(q) %}
```

Comment: Thanks, Joel. I ended up adding another field to Charge that stores the event entry ID, and all is good. Loving Charge 2.1 - building a fairly complex restaurant booking system around it that includes a ton a features for the restaurant staff to manage reservations, refund cancellations, and much more!